# How to get this telerik reporting chart to render correctly.

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-reporting

I have constructed a collection of data series items. Each data series has multiple data points.

I am binding all this to a bar chart. That data binding is working fine however for some reason beyond my comprehension the reporting engine has decided that all my bar chart items will be aligned to the left side of the chart.

Currently the way my report is rendering is unacceptable. Is there a way to fix this (Please see screenshot)

Cheers !

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here was that all my data was bound to one `ChartSeries`. Creating one `ChartSeries` per each set of bars worked perfectly.